# Pass another parameter to NumberFormatCustom(props) React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following function called NumberFormatCustom.

**NumberFormatCustom :**

```
function NumberFormatCustom(props) {
const { inputRef, onChange, ...other } = props;

return (
    <NumberFormat
        {...other}
        getInputRef={inputRef}
        onValueChange={values => {
            onChange({
                target: {
                    name: props.name,
                    value: values.value
                }
            });
        }}
        thousandSeparator=","
        allowNegative={false}
        decimalSeparator="."
        decimalScale={2}
        maxLength={12}
        fixedDecimalScale={true}
        allowEmptyFormatting={i}
    //prefix="S/"
    //mask="_" //nunca los entendí
    //format="##.###" //nunca los entendí
    // isNumericString
    />
 );
}
```

That I have implemented like,

```
 <TextField
    InputProps={{
       inputComponent: NumberFormatCustom,
       className: classes.finput
    }} />
```

but i want to send another parameter to use inside function, for example in property **allowEmptyFormatting**, but i don't know how to do it. can someone please help me with this.

this does not work with the current NumberFormatCustom function:

```
 <TextField InputProps={{ inputComponent: NumberFormatCustom(null,'another parameter'),
                      className: classes.finput }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a function, which receives a bunch of parameters and returns a component, then you can pass any arguments to the function, like this:

```
const createNumberFormatCustom = (...params)=> (props) => {
 // params will be available in the body of your component
 const { inputRef, onChange, ...other } = props;
 
 return (
   <NumberFormat
      ...
   />
 );}
```

and use it like this:

```
<TextField InputProps={{ inputComponent: createNumberFormatCustom('another parameter'),
                      className: classes.finput }}
```

to solve the losing focus problem which you mentioned in the comment, there are some solutions:

1- if you want to pass some additional params just one time you can call `createNumberFormatCustom` outside of your component and pass the returned component as `inputComponent`, like this:

```
const MyComp = createNumberFormatCustom('custom params'); // don't call it inside the body of component, because whenever component rerenders, it makes a new component
<TextField
  ...
InputProps={{
    inputComponent: MyComp,
 }}
/>
```

You can learn more about this trick Here: [Higher-Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

2- if you want to read some values inside the component and pass it to `createNumberFormatCustom` but again for the just first render you can use `React.useMemo` or `React.useRef`, like this:

```
const MyComp = React.useMemo(()=> createNumberFormatCustom('customparams'), []);
<TextField
    ...
    InputProps={{
     inputComponent: MyComp,
    }}
 />
```

or:

```
const MyComp = React.useRef(createNumberFormatCustom('custom params'))
<TextField
  InputProps={{
    inputComponent: MyComp.current,
  }}
/>
```

3- if you want to dynamically send some parameters to `NumberFormatCustom`,the better solution is to use materialUI approach to send attributes to `inputComponent`, like this:

```
<TextField
  InputProps={{
   inputComponent: NumberFormatCustom,
   inputProps: { param1: 'value1', param2:'value2' }
  }}
/>
```

and inside `NumberFormatCustom` read custom params like this:

```
function NumberFormatCustom(props) {
  const { param1, param2, ...other } = props;
  console.log({param1, param2})

  return (
   <NumberFormat .../>
 );
}
```

Comment: you right, can you please explain why i need to change function to const, and why props is not exactly a parameter but its more like a return type (or at least i think that), and some detail about sintax, maybe is too broad to explain but i will apprecciate too much, and if this is a easy sintax topic, because im not too familiar with javascript sintax, so what subject i need to review to understand better this kind of syntax, thank you in advance.

Comment: Actually you don't need to change your function syntax, it's optional to write your function as `arrow-function`. you can learn more about it here: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: in the above code, actually we have a function which returns another function, nested function has access to the parent function arguments, this trick named `Closure` in javascript. Here you can learn more about Closure: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures . I believe that if you take a look at these two topics (`Closure` and `arrow-function`) above syntax will be so easy for you.

Comment: Hi, im here again, i was testing solution and its working at compile time, but when i use the component, is losing the focus, so i need to click in the textfield again to continue writing, i think that this is because is change function to const, can you please help me again?

Comment: Hi, could you provide your code in https://codesandbox.io/ ?

Comment: here is, https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-margulis-vtvpy?file=/src/App.tsx, this is my currenct code, so when i change to your code, the issue appear, thank you so much for you time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241122/discussion-between-saeed-shamloo-and-juan-ruiz-de-castilla).